# PYthon: using the virtual environment version of a binary

Tags: python, python-venv

**My Problem**

I have Pytest installed both inside a virtual environment and globally.

When I source the venv and run

```sh
pytest app/test.py
```

The global version runs, which does not have the relevant modules installed. Therefore, I have to use:

```sh
venv/bin/pytest app/test.py
```

This makes it difficult to automate, because a test script should hopefully run both locally (venv) and on the CI/CD (container, Pytest installed globally) using the same command.

**My Question**

Is there a way to run a Python binary from the virtual environment bin directory without specifying its full pathname?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the binary, run the module. This way Python defaults to the venv before looking at the global scope.

```sh
python -m pytest app/test.py
```